# Faster way to check moduli in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I've been writing simulation codes for a while, and there's always a main loop that looks like this, in this case in Python:

```
while t<totalTimesteps:
    
    t += 1
    processOneTimestep()

    outputData()
```

the line `outputData()` writes results to a file one per timestep for analysis. This writing can take quite a bit of time, and we usually don't need the state of whatever we are doing in every single timestep, so it will usually look like this:

```
while t<totalTimesteps:
    
    t += 1
    processOneTimestep()

    if t%N == 0:
        outputData()
```

where `N` is an integer that sets how often we write. Assuming the simulation and writing themselves are very optimized, is there a way in Python to accelerate that modulus check, or to use inline Python magic to make it faster? Is that `if` line as fast as it can be in Python?

Comment: You probably shouldn't write to the file in the simulation loop. Instead collect the data in some data structure (list, pandas data table, or whatever makes sense). Then write to the file at the end of the program.

Comment: And for your question; the if and the modulus will take shorter time than almost anything else in your program.

Comment: Hi @Stefan I know it will take less time than almost everything else, I was just wondering... Also I have to output data in the loop because there are several gigabytes of data produced, I can't keep them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's faster, but you could use nested loops.

```
for tsteps in range(0, totalTimesteps, N):
    for t in range(tsteps, min(tsteps+N, totalTimesteps)):
        processOneTimestep()
    outputData()
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks for your answer, but I've tried it in a couple of setups and it doesn't produce any noticeable speedup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use map to apply a function to all index. To get all the different index you could use range, and you could use a lambda function to get a more concise code.

```
N=3 #example N

map(
    lambda i: (processOneTimestep(), outputData()) if i%N==0 else processOneTimestep(),
    range(totalTimesteps)
)
```

This code would execute both functions when `i%N==0` in other case will only execute `processOneTimestep()`